# Renaming Vuex module thinks the old one is still there

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuex4

I literally just tried to rename my modules and I'm getting a pointless error. I had a module called "speed". I renamed it and all references to "team". Now I'm getting this error
`Error: Missing module "speed" for path "speed/".`

Old:

```js
const store = createStore<State>({
  modules: {
    speed: { ... }
  }
})
```

New:

```js
const store = createStore<State>({
  modules: {
    team: { ... }
  }
})
```

The state, getters, actions, etc. inside of the module is unchanged.

I've restarted my service, restarted my IDE, restarted my computer. No changes.

I'm using "webpack": "^5.40.0", "vuex": "^4.0.2", "vue": "^3.1.1", "typescript": "^4.3.4"

Literally the word 'speed' is no where in any of my files.

Comment: How about directory? Looks like the folder is still called `speed`

Comment: It's unknown where the error happens. IDE? Build command? They are different tools and can work differently

Answer (score 0):

If you are persisting your store using either cookies or localStorage, `Ctrl+Shift+Delete` your browser (delete your cache) because it might still be having a reference the old module. Again, this will only work if the error is originating from your browser and not the terminal or IDE. If it fails, you can try a private browser window or use a different browser altogether